# Key is CORRECT: "not authorized" to decrypt?

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, remote-desktop

On ubuntu 14.04 I installed Xfce to make remote desktop work. 
On win7 when i rdp to the machine and attempt to mount an encrypted usb device I get "not authorized to perform operation" message.
I've attempted to do this from command line but even with the sudo password do not get access while trying to decrypt from there "access denied or volume not present" message

Comment: If you are connecting to a Windows machine and getting this error there, then that has nothing to do with Ubuntu and so is off topic here.

Comment: @psusi I think this is a question about polkit not allowing remote users to mount local resources?

Comment: I am connecting to an ubuntu machine from windows.  Within the remote session, I get this error connecting to a usb drive on the remote (Ubuntu) Machine

Answer (score 1):

Remote users are not allowed to mount removable media, which are presumed to have been inserted by whomever is sitting at the console.  If you are an administrator, then you can use `sudo` to gain root permissions and then use the `mount` command to mount it.  Identify the device in question with `lsblk` then assuming it is /dev/sdb1:

```
sudo mkdir /media/yourname/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/yourname/usb
```

Don't forget to `sudo umount /media/yourname` when you are done using it.

Comment: I'll give this a try, but within the remote session I attempted to input the correct sudo password and still got the access denied error attempting to mount sdb0.  Do I need to modify my remote user config file on the server to add permissions to removable media? or is that even possible?

Comment: I have the result:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'

The volume needs to be decrypted, do I do that within the mount command syntax?

Comment: So I decrypted the volume and was able to mount it.  Thanks for your help!